# multivariable non-linear curve_fit with scipy

Tags: math, scipy, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I have been trying to use scipy.optimize curve_fit using multiple variables. It works fine with the test code I created but when I try to implement this on my actual data I keep getting the following error

> TypeError:  only arrays length -1 can be converted to python scalars

The shape of the arrays and the data types of their elements in my test code and actual code are exactly the same so I am confused as to why I get this error.

**Test code:**

```
    import numpy as np 
    import scipy 
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

    def func(x,a,b,c):
          return a+b*x[0]**2+c*x[1]
    x_0=np.array([1,2,3,4])
    x_1=np.array([5,6,7,8])
    X=scipy.array([x_0,x_1])
    Y=func(X,3.1,2.2,2.1)
    popt, pcov=curve_fit(func,X,Y)
```

**Actual code:**

```
    f=open("Exp_Fresnal.csv", 'rb')
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
         Qz.append(row[0])
         Ref.append(row[1])
         Ref_F.append(row[2])
    Qz_arr,Ref_Farr=scipy.array((Qz)),scipy.array((Ref_F))
    x=scipy.array([Qz_arr,Ref_Farr]

    def func(x,d,sig_int,sig_cp):
         return x[1]*(x[0]*d*(math.exp((-sig_int**2)*(x[0]**2)/2)/(1-cmath.exp(complex(0,1)*x[0]*d)*math.exp((-sig_cp**2)*(x[0]**2)/2))))**2

    Y=scipy.array((Ref))
    popt, pcov=curve_fit(func,x,Y)
```

**EDIT**
Here is the full error message

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "DCM_03.py", line 46, in <module>
>       popt, pcov=curve_fit(func,x,Y)
>     File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 651, in curve_fit
>       res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kwargs)
>     File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq
>       shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
>     File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
>       res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
>     File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 453, in _general_function
>       return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
>     File "DCM_03.py", line 40, in func
>       return (0.062/(2*x))**4*(x*d*(math.exp((-sig_int**2)*(x**2)/2)/(1-cmath.exp(complex(0,1)*x*d)*math.exp((-sig_cp**2)*(x**2)/2))))**2
>   TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Your code sample won't run without the field `Exp_Fresnal.csv`. Could you provide this document or a code that doesn't rely on an external file?

Comment: I don't think I can attach document files to a question it is essentially just 3 columns of data that are 155 rows each. Also the test code does not require any document to run. I included the actual code because the test code works but the actual code does not. I am not sure if it is something to do with the way I am importing the data ?

Comment: Show the full error. There should be much more information contained. The line ```Y=func(X,3.1,2.2,2.1)``` looks suspicious.

Comment: Answer to @Charco: math.exp() only takes in a number, whereas numpy.exp() can take in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The problem for some reason was the use of `math.exp` and `cmath.exp` in the fitting function `func`. In place of these functions I used `np.exp()`. I am not completely sure the reason why though.